# How to get our own date time format in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, date

In my application , i have a control which is displaying current time in HH:mm:ss format. My question is if format is HH mm ss then, how this format is converted back to HH:mm:ss format

ex
03-08-2016 10:30:45 ==> my required format
03-08-2016 10 30 45 ==> current format. or it may be any other format

How can i get required format?...

Comment: It isn't clear, why do you want to manipulate format strings at all. What do you try to achieve? Do you want to change display format for your control, or you want something else?

Comment: @Naveen: Understand the fact the you need to display the time part of DateTime object in a special format. There is a difference between parsing a string into DateTime object and creating a formatted string from DateTime object. Always store your date time in a DateTime object and display it the way you want. Answer from *un-lucky* shows how to get a formatted (your format) string of date time from a DateTime object.

Comment: So, are you asking how to format datetime in C#?  If so, go to Google and type "C# format datetime" (without quotes).  The very first hit will be your answer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime class has a `.ToString()` method which accepts format string as it's argument. Please have a [look at this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can get your required format as follows:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var formattedDate = now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH mm ss");
```

Comment: My required format is dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.. For the above posts its giving "08-03-2016 10 51 10" but i need "08-03-2016 10:51:10"

Comment: @NaveenkumarR you just need to put the `:` in the Time format as `HH:mm:ss` see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Let the `dateInput` be the date time object, and the `dateFormatString` be the required format. then you can use the `.ToString()` method to get the formatted date string; This can be achieved by using the following code:

```
string dateFormatString="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string formattedDateString =  dateInput.ToString(dateFormatString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you can get the string value from your control that displays in `MM-dd-yyyy HH mm ss` format, you can use [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert it back to a `DateTime` variable.

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(controlDT.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy HH mm ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var newDateTimeString = datetime.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: It is still not giving my required format .. that colon is missing in converted string..

Comment: @NaveenkumarR it should work now, I updated my answer.

Comment: sir kindly change your system time format to h m s t.. then tell me whether its working or not..?

Comment: @NaveenkumarR which one should I change? the short time or long time format?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your current date time format `dd-MM-yyyy HH mm ss` like `03-08-2016 10 30 45` then you can convert your current format to `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss` as follow

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact("03-08-2016 10 30 45", "dd-MM-yyyy HH mm ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newdate = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

using same mechanism you can convert any format to another

Answer (score 0):

Easy way around. Try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string dt = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

The output produced will be *(as per your required format)*:

> 03-08-2016 05:25:47

Answer (score -4):

Convert like this:

```
 var date= DateTime.Now;
 var Yourrequeired= date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH: mm: ss");
```

Comment: Try to change your system long time format to h m s t and check whether u can get required format ....If system is running in default format the above conversion works fine...what if some custom format is set?...